# Elasticsearch distance query exception throwing

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I have written the following query to sort by nearest user first, and then by remaining users but when I run this query on kibana, it throws an **exception** and I don't know what the mistake is?

**Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "user"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "1000km",
          "location": {
            "lat": 24.71532,
            "lon": 46.66479
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sort": [
      {
        "_geo_distance": {
          "location": {
            "lat": 24.71532,
            "lon": 46.66479
          },
          "order": "asc",
          "unit": "km",
          "distance_type": "plane"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

Exception

{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
        "line": 21,
        "col": 5
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
    "line": 21,
    "col": 5
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I found this code on the elastic search official website. when I run this query without the sort filter this query works, but when I add the sort filter U get an exception.

Kindly guide me to solve this query issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `sort` section needs to go at the same level as the `query` section, not inside it:

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "location": {
          "lat": 24.71532,
          "lon": 46.66479
        },
        "order": "asc",
        "unit": "km",
        "distance_type": "plane"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "user"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "1000km",
          "location": {
            "lat": 24.71532,
            "lon": 46.66479
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```